# Angular 7 - background in a div not working

Tags: css, angular, background

I have an Angular 7 project structured the following way:

```
-|src
--|app
---|modules
-----|home
```

`home` is a component having

`home.component.html:`

```
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

`home.component.scss:`

```
.wrapper {
    background: url(../../../assets/background.jpg);
}
```

For some strange reason, the background.jpg is not showing on the page. I noticed when I refresh the page with emptying the cache, in developer tools source segment, there is a background.jpg image and when I click "open in new tab", it opens the image in the new tab.

Comment: Does the `.wrapper` have any content? You can't show a background of something with no size.

Comment: When I put some content, the background is not for the whole page, but only for the part where that content is.

Comment: Does it display with a static external URL image or say a base64 inline? Is it the same result for the relative path between dev and prod build configs via the CLI? Are you just forgetting to enclose the url path as string via `url("../../blah.jpg")`? Just going down the order of deduction....

Comment: The path is correct @Paulie_D 's answer is a partial solution, but now I need it to extend to 100% of the page's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The Angular was messing the wrappers. I found about :host and :host-context and used /deep property, so the CSS was styling the host wrapper, and not the wrapper that it was in

Answer (score 0):

Probably the asset is in another directory and the div maybe doesn't have size:

```
.wrapper {
    background: url(../assets/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```